# How to get Value in Spinner and pass the Value to url for translate

Tags: android, hashmap, android-spinner, key-value, google-translate

I am developing a **translate app** on Android Studio. I have created my Language Key and Value using **Map**, I want to pass the value of key selected by the user to URL. for example if the user selects French from Spinner, "fr" should be pass to url for translate. how can I achieve this? below is my **Java Activity** Code. I am using the latest Android Studio.

```
     spinner = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    final Map<String, String> flanguages = new HashMap<String, String>();
    flanguages.put("Arabic", "ar");
    flanguages.put("English", "en");
    flanguages.put("French", "fr");
    flanguages.put("Hausa", "ha");
    flanguages.put("Igbo", "ig");
    flanguages.put("Yoruba", "yo");
    flanguages.put("Japanese", "ja");

     final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(flanguages.keySet());


    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    spinner.setPrompt("Select Language To Translate");
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); //returns country Full-name
```

This line gives your the selected item i.e the country name but not its abbreviation. To get the abbreviation to use the HashMap(use the Key to get the Value).Ex: Here key is "France" and its value is "fr"

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String key = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); //ex: this gives France
       // String key = list.get(position); // or use can use this,//ex: this also gives France

        String countryCode = flanguages.get(key); //ex: this gives "fr"
        //api integration

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Amit. this works fine. i used the Countrycode line and my app work fine now

Answer (score 1):

In your onItemSelected callback

```
String key = list.get(position);
String countryCode = flanguages.get(key);
```

countryCode is what you need